# make4ht place footnotes container inside "main-content" container

Tags: footnotes, tex4ht, html, make4ht

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{article} 

\begin{document}
    Test \footnote{This is a test!}
\end{document}
```

When I compile using this configuration file (.cfg):

```
\Preamble{xhtml,html5,fn-in} 

\Configure{@BODY}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<main class="main-content">}}
\Configure{@/BODY}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{</main>}}

\begin{document} 
\EndPreamble
```

I get something like

```
<body>
   <main class='main-content'> ... </main>
   <div class='footnotes'> ... </div>
</body>
```

How can I transform it so the footnotes be inside the "main-content" container? Like this:

```
<body>
   <main class='main-content'>
      ...
      <div class='footnotes'> ... </div>
   </main>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `fn-in` option writes footnotes in `\Configure{BODY}`, which is inserted after `\Configure{@/BODY}`, so your closing `</main>` tag is inserted before footnotes. But, you can insert footnotes manually, which will prevent the default footnote box:

```latex
\Preamble{xhtml,html5,fn-in} 

\Configure{@BODY}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP\HCode{<main class="main-content">}\par\ShowPar}

\catcode`\:=11 % we need to support the ":" character in command names
\Configure{@/BODY}{\ifvmode\IgnorePar\fi\EndP
\ifvoid \fn:box\else
   \HCode{<div class="footnotes">}\box\fn:box\HCode{</div>}
   \IgnorePar\EndP
\fi
\HCode{\Hnewline</main>}
}%

\catcode`\:=12

\begin{document} 
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:

```html
   <main class='main-content'> 
<!-- l. 4 --><p class='indent'>   Test <span class='footnote-mark'><a href='#fn1x0' id='fn1x0-bk'><sup class='textsuperscript'>1</sup></a></span><a id='x1-2f1'></a>
   <div class='footnotes'><a id='x1-3x'></a>
<!-- l. 4 --><p class='indent'>     <span class='footnote-mark'><a href='#fn1x0-bk' id='fn1x0'><sup class='textsuperscript'>1</sup></a></span><span class='cmr-8'>This is a test!</span></p>                                                                                             </div> 
</main>
```